# PHP Page Records display logic

Tags: php, logic, paging

On single page, I am displaying 20 records at a time and with that records, I am generating PDF with their profile to export / download for admin.

Now, what i want is, for ex. on 4th Page i am passing, 4 while actual records i will have will be 61 ~ 80.. and on..

for example:

```
3rd page: 41 ~ 60 records
4th page: 61 ~ 80 records
5th page: 81 ~ 100 records and so on..
```

Does Any one have idea, How can i pass **dynamic Start and End query limit** in this case?

Comment: You are looking for a pagination tutorial. See e.g. [php sample script for pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3615515)

Comment: Also in question: Which PDF library do you use?

Comment: tcPDF library we're using in cakephp

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Is the problem with generating the PDF or is it about fetching the right records? Could you update the question with this information?

Comment: the actual problem was to get 20 records on each pages like on 1st page: 20 records, 2nd page: 21 to 40 records, 3rd page: 41 to 60 pages etc.. and found solution as well, thank you all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple (don't consider following as valid `PHP` code! Because.... it's not):

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$records_on_page = X;
$offset = $records_on_page * ($page-1);
$limit = "LIMIT $offset,$records_on_page"

page, offset, on_page
1, 00, 20
2, 20, 20
3, 40, 20
4, 60, 20
5, 80, 20
etc.
```

all logic.