# Separate Items of an Array Over Different Pages

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php sample script for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615515/php-sample-script-for-pagination)

Suppose after a Process, My MySQL Table Returns an array into some variable. The array containts title and content of various posts/articles.

I want to show only 5 items of that array on the homepage. And the user would have to click on next page or page 2, to get to the next 5 items.

How do i do that kind of thing in PHP ?

Each Post of mine has an ID column in the Databases, which uses Auto_increment. So, the laest post would have largest value of ID.

Comment: search for `pagination` e.g. at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

you can change order by ASC too, while click on next, pass offset value as 5, and each subsequent click add offset + 5

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong you want to implement something like pagination.
Just check out how stackoverflow implements that,whenever you click on a link to 
view more message they pass around query like that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest
Where value of page specify the requested page.Now suppose you wish to display
only 10 items per page then you can make a query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SOME_CONDITION LIMIT (pageNo-1)*NoOfRecordsPerPage,NoOfRecordsPerPage
```