# How to show 5 post each page with next & previous button feature?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page named `'job.php'`, currently this page is showing all posted job. But now I want to show only 5 latest posts. And if anyone want to check the previous posts, they can click next button thus more 5 posts will be seen. There should be a previous button too.

Following is my code:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY ID DESC");
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($result1);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
     $cat=$row1['Category'];
     $title=$row1['Title'];
     echo "Job field: $cat<br/> Title: $title<br/>";
}
```

N:B: It's not pagination. I don't want to show page numbers, just want to show next & previous button.

Comment: Step 1: learn how to use the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) keyword.

Comment: are you using any freamework like Codeigniter or Zend ?

Comment: Only 366,000 results, but [this](http://www.google.com/?q=php+mysql+pagination) should help.

Comment: No I am not, Sujit Singh.

Comment: may b u can use one of php pagination library of pagination or use **LIMIT** here is the example http://www.awcore.com/dev/1/3/Create-Awesome-PHPMYSQL-Pagination_en can help you

Comment: @Shahriar No, it **is** pagination, whether or not you're showing the page numbers. I don't see why you think it is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php sample script for pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615515/php-sample-script-for-pagination)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are 100s of articles available on the Internet

- [Create Awesome PHP/MYSQL Pagination](http://www.awcore.com/dev/1/3/Create-Awesome-PHPMYSQL-Pagination_en)
- [PHP / MySQL select data and split on pages](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html)

#### If you want to do on your own:

- Use `LIMIT` keywords in your query.
- Pass the `page` and the multiplier to the `LIMIT`.

#### Some code

```
<?php
  $limit = 5;
  $start = (int)(($page - 1 ) * $limit);
  $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["page"]);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $start, {(int)$page + $limit}"
?>
```

Comment: There's a SQL injection vulnerability in this code - fancy fixing? `:)` (Ping me and I'll undownvote).

Comment: Also, I think you should have `$start = ($page - 1 ) * $limit;` so you can do `LIMIT $start, $limit` - I think the format is `<start ordinal>, <number of records>`.

Comment: You probably also want to untaint the page using `(int)` rather than escaping, so you can be sure you're passing an integer (it'll crash otherwise).

Comment: @halfer Check now? I have updated the code as per your guidance. Will take these things in mind, when I use and answer again. :)

Comment: Great, undownvoted and upvoted. Last point: it's harmless to `(int)` on the `$start` assignment, but since `$page` is being treated as a number, it's not necessary.

Comment: @halfer Thanks. We need support from people like you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1) In the query itself by using LIMIT

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1, 5");
```

2 ) By using loop

```
$i = 0;
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    if($i < 5) {
       $cat=$row1['Category'];
       $title=$row1['Title'];
       echo "Job field: $cat<br/> Title: $title<br/>";
       $i++;
    }
}
```

You can pass the current value to URL and get it back by using $_GET..

Comment: Your `LIMIT` should be `0, 5` instead of `1, 5` for the first set of results.

Comment: @Supericy ya.. it should be dynamic know. He can get it from the prev index value. It is just an example. He can modify this based on his requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
Select * from table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel its better to use pagination. If you want dont want to show page nos, better hide it or just modify the code. If you planning to do it manually its a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT in you mysql query:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 5");
```