# php loop, pause and continue when user clicks a button

Tags: php

I have 2026 image records to display on screen and it's too many to show all at once. I want to display the first 50, pause, wait for user to click a button. Then list the next 50, and so on. Is this a good solution? How can I do this? I want to **echo javascript commands with php to display groups of 50 records.**

```
<?php

$X = 0; $limit = 1000;

foreach ($i; $i <= $limit; $i++) {

$X++;

echo "<div> </div>";

if ($X % 50 == 0) 

{echo '<button> continue </button>';}

}
?>
```

Comment: You will need to make use of AJAX. Send a request to your server(PHP code) to get the next 50 and so on. See if this gets you started https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: use php pagination? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615548/10230696

Comment: I'm not using SQL. My source is https://communitychessclub.com/diagram.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server language. You send a request, it gives you a response, there is no interactivity. You need to look into AJAX to get the result you want.

Comment: What about if I used javascript?

Comment: AJAX stands for asynchronous JavaScript and XML, so basically yes, you need to use JavaScript to fetch the content dynamically and insert it into your page.

Comment: I realize that php is a server side language. But I need to use php and echo the javascript "<script>" code.